# yii\debug\Module::checkAccess

Tags: php, yii

Поставил debug панель на сайт, добавив свой ip

```
if (!YII_ENV_TEST) {
        // configuration adjustments for 'dev' environment
        $config['bootstrap'][] = 'debug';
        $config['modules']['debug'] = [
            'class' => 'yii\debug\Module',
            'allowedIPs' => ['22.22.22.22'],
        ];

        $config['bootstrap'][] = 'gii';
        $config['modules']['gii'] = [
            'class' => 'yii\gii\Module',
        ];
    }
```

Но в логи в админке теперь записывается любое посещение любой страницы от любого пользователя наподобие такого

```
Access to debugger is denied due to IP address restriction. The requesting IP address is 11.11.11.11
```

Как убрать такую запись в лог?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Настроить

```html
'components' => [
        'user' => [
           
        ],
        'log' => [
            'traceLevel' => YII_DEBUG ? 3 : 0,
            'targets' => [
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                    'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
```

Comment: Не работает для меня

Answer (score 4):

Отключите логирование дебаггера.

В файле `common/config/base.php` добавьте `'yii\debug\Module*'` сюда:

```
'components' => [
    'log' => [
        'targets' => [
            'db' => [
                'except' => ['yii\debug\Module*'],
            ],
        ],
    ],
],
```

И если такие ошибки приходят на почту, добавьте `'yii\debug\Module*'` сюда:

```
$config['components']['log']['targets']['email'] = [
    'except' => ['yii\debug\Module*'],
];
```